# How to convert a panorama item into page/data grid

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I am new to Windows phone dev. I am following this excellent article ( http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Weather_in_Windows_Phone_7 ) and have learnt something about how to load xml data and show it as a useful info in a paronama view. But now instead of panorama i want it to be shown as a page. I am not sure if its in a page tag or data grid tag that I should work with. Can someone please help me with how to convert this piece of code to some thing which can be displayed in a page

```
// create PanoramaItem            
PanoramaItem panoramaItem = new PanoramaItem();            
panoramaItem.Header = queries[query];            
// modify header to show only city (not the country)            
int index = queries[query].IndexOf(",");            
if (index != -1) 
panoramaItem.Header = queries[query].Substring(0,queries[query].IndexOf(","));
else panoramaItem.Header = queries[query];            
// use ForecastTemplate in Panorama Item     
panoramaItem.ContentTemplate=(DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["ForecastTemplate"];
panoramaItem.Content = pio; // add Panorama Item to Panorama
Panorama.Items.Add(panoramaItem); // query next city forecast
```

Answer (score -1):

- At first, be sure that Pivot is useless for you. Its like Panorama, but Pivot :) See differences [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnmobiledevs/archive/2011/12/06/like-a-boss-understanding-the-difference-between-panorama-and-pivot-in-windows-phone.aspx), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030313/difference-between-panorama-and-pivot-control), [here(nice one)](http://ux.artu.tv/?p=234) or [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Part-5-Panorama-and-Pivot-controls.aspx)
- Tried to paste some code here, but SO is not showing tags. So, take a look at <.Grid.ColumnDefinitions> and <.Grid.RawDefinitions>. Dots at the beginning are just for rendering.

Comment: I hate downvoters, which are not providing a reason of their actions. Kindergarden.